# Transforming PO to Item Receipt via SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm trying to transform a PO to an "itemreceipt". This code keeps crashing and I am getting the error message:

> INVALID_INITIALIZE_REF: You can not initialize itemreceipt: invalid reference.

```js
var item_recepit = record.transform({
    fromType: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER,
    fromId: 59669735,
    toType: record.Type.ITEM_RECEIPT             
});
```

Comment: You are talking about itemreceipt yet in your code you have item_recepit, does the itemreceipt exists at all?

Comment: Hello Anton- I was under the impression that the transform creates the itemreceipt.  In other examples Ive seen this is how transforms work. I will very though, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Hello.  Can you share more of your code, at least up until the line where the error was thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do transforms from a Purchase Order to Item Receipt if the Purchase Order is a Special Order Purchase Order and not a Drop Ship Purchase Order.  From NetSuite's documentation:

[image: image in NetSuite documentation stating that the transform does not work for dropship purchase orders]